# Lightstreamer java se client maven

Tags: maven, lightstreamer

I'm trying to use the java client sdk of lightstreamer and I feel like I have an extremely basic question.

When adding the dependencies to my `pom.xml` like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>lightstreamer</id>
        <url>https://www.lightstreamer.com/repo/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightstreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ls-javase-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I then only get the following packages in the *com.lightstreamer:ls-javase-client:4.3.0*

```
io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.31.Final
io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.31.Final
io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:4.1.31.Final
com.cedarsoftware:json-io:4.10.0
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
```

I don't have any of the classes described here:
https://lightstreamer.com/api/ls-javase-client/4.3.0/

Perhaps it has been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

The list of libraries you mentioned are the second level dependencies of the library itself, and should be listed in the file ls-javase-client-4.3.0.pom.

But, the jar file named ls-javase-client-4.3.0.jar should contain the actual library. Maybe something went wrong with your dependency solver? Any warning or error in maven execution?
In any case you could get the jar directly from here: https://www.lightstreamer.com/repo/maven/com/lightstreamer/ls-javase-client/4.3.0/ls-javase-client-4.3.0.jar